# Is it possible to use codepush with multiple root components?

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

my index.js file registers multiple root components like following

```
import RNUserInfo from 'custom_auth/react/user/user-info/components/entry/user-info'
AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNUserInfo', () => RNUserInfo);
import RNProduct from 'product/react/components/entry/product-entry'
AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNProduct', () => RNProduct);
```

Is it possible to use codepush with the above setup?

I can only find example which has single root component